# Como pasar info de una pagina a otra con php $_SESSION[]

Tags: php, session

tengo esta tabla que **muestra todos los usuarios registrados**:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-5">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellidos</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Password</th>
                                <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                                <th>Pais</th>
                                <th>Fecha Registro</th>
                                <th>Operaciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php if (isset($usuarios)) {

                                foreach ($usuarios as $usuario ) { ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $usuario['id'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['nombre'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['apellidos'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['email'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['password'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['pais'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo  $usuario['fecha_registro'] ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-info" href="">Editar</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Borrar</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            <?php   }


                             } ?>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

La tabla es cargada por este fichero php :
**listarUsuarios.php**

```
<?php 
    include_once 'conexion.php';


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios;";

    // var_dump($sql);

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    // var_dump($result);



    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $usuarios = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($usuarios, $row);
        }


        // foreach ($usuarios as $usuario ) {
            //  echo $usuario['id'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['nombre'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['apellidos'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['email'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['password'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['fecha_registro'] . "<br>";
            //  echo $usuario['fecha_nacimiento'] . "<br>";
        // }



    }

 ?>
```

Despues tengo este otro fichero **sesiones.php** para maneja las sesiones:

```
<?php 
    public function borrar_sesiones(){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function iniciar_sesiones(){
        session_start();
    }

    public function añadir_sesion($clave,$valor){
        $_SESSION[$clave] = $valor;
    }

    public function borrar_sesion($clave){
        if (isset($_SESSION[$clave])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$clave])
        }
    }




 ?>
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando clicko en **actualizar** en la tabla de **listar-php** quieor que guarde en una sesion el id para poder usarlo, pero no se como podria hacer que desde ese `<a>` almacene en la session esto : `$_SESSION['id']` y finalmente redirigirme a el fichero **guardar.php** que actuara de la siguiente manera:

Si existe la **sesion** `$_SESSION['id']` **guardar.php** lo que hara sera **ACTUALIZAR** cargando previamente en los inputs los datos correspondiente a la BD y si **NO** existe la **sesion** `$_SESSION['id']` pues que lo trate como un form de registro normal y corriente. A continuacion dejo mi fichero **guardar.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guardar Usuarios</title>
    <?php include '../static/bootstrap.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>



    <?php include '../static/menu.php' ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center mt-5">Guardar usuario</h1>
                <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
                    <form  action="../procedimientos/guardarUsuario.php" method="post">
                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" id="apellidos" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Introduce tu email">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Pais</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pais" class="form-control" id="pais" placeholder="Introduce tu pais">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" class="form-control" id="fecha_nacimiento">
                      </div>


                      <button type="submit" class=" mt-2 btn btn-success">Guardar Usuario</button>

                    </form>
                <?php} ?>



                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>

                    <form  action="../procedimientos/guardarUsuario.php" method="post">
                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" id="apellidos" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Introduce tu email">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Pais</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pais" class="form-control" id="pais" placeholder="Introduce tu pais">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group mt-5">
                        <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" class="form-control" id="fecha_nacimiento">
                      </div>


                      <button type="submit" class=" mt-2 btn btn-success">Guardar Usuario</button>

                </form>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php include '../static/jquery.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y el **fichero.php** asociado a esta vista es : **guardarUsuario.php**

```
<?php 
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    if (isset($_POST['nombre']) and 
        isset($_POST['apellidos']) and 
        isset($_POST['email']) and  
        isset($_POST['password']) and 
        isset($_POST['pais']) and  
        isset($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']) ) {

        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $pais = $_POST['pais'];
        $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];


        var_dump($nombre);
        var_dump($apellidos);
        var_dump($email);
        var_dump($password);
        var_dump($pais);
        var_dump($fecha_nacimiento);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos,email, password,pais,fecha_nacimiento) 
         VALUES('".$nombre."','".$apellidos."','".$email."','".$password."','".$pais."','".$fecha_nacimiento."');";


        var_dump($sql);


        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        var_dump($result);


        header("location: ../vistas/listar.php");

    }




 ?>
```

Entonces, resumiendo un poco, lo que pretendo es que en la tabla de  **listar.php** si clicka a editar o eliminar que le pase de alguna manera el id del usuario para poder hacer lo que quiera. Basicamente pasr el id de un lado para otro, de forma segura obviamente.